# Web Browser zoom via javascript and graceful degrading

Tags: browser, zooming, accessibility, font-size

I'm working on a web project that has some accessibility features mandated by the client, including a "font size changer" to allow the font size to be increased for visually impaired users.

Despite my arguments that a better experience will be had by using the built-in zoom features in the browser, the client has insisted that their users will not know to use these built-in features, so we must provide a text size changing widget.

What I'd like to do, if possible, is cause these page elements to invoke the browser's own zoom functionality (Ctrl + + in firefox, for example). If the browser doesn't support this method of zooming, then I might fall back to increasing the font size with css.

How can I best implement this kind of feature? Is it even possible? Is there some solution that I've overlooked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way as far as I know to use the browser's built in function. However it can be done with CSS3 or javascript. for a CSS3 example look here: http://www.css3.com/css-zoom/